# .Net XML Serialization and Escaped or Encoded characters

Tags: xml-serialization, escaping

I'm using XML Serialization heavily in a web service (the contracts pass complex types as params). Recently I noticed that the .Net XML Serialization engine is escaping some of the well known 5 reserved characters that must be escaped when included within an element (<, >, &, ' and "). My first reaction was "good old .Net, always looking out for me".

But then I started experimenting and noticed it is only escaping the <, > and &, and for some reason not the apostrophy and double quotes. For example if I return this literal string in a field within a complex type from my service:

```
 Bad:<>&'":Data
```

This is what is transferred over the wire (as seen from Fiddler):

```
 Bad:&lt;&gt;&amp;'":Data
```

Has anyone run into this or understand why this is? Is the serializer simply overlooking them or is there a reason for this? As I understand it the ' and " are not by spec valid within an xml element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax), for regular content and markup:

- `&` always needs to be escaped as `&amp;` because it's the escape character
- `<` always needs to be escaped as `&lt;` since it determines the start of an element. It even has to be escaped within attributes as a safety and to make writing parser error detection simpler.
- `>` does not need to be escaped as `&gt;` but often is for symmetry with `<`
- `'` needs to be escaped as `&apos;` only if in an attribute delimited by `'`
- `"` needs to be escaped as `&quot;` only if in an attribute delimited by `"`

Inside of processing instructions, comments and `CDATA` sections, the rules change some, but the details are in the [2.4 Character Data and Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax) portion of the spec.

Your serializer is trying to do you a favor by keeping the file somewhat human-readable.

(Each of the above may also be escaped using their numeric equivalents.)

Answer (score 0):

XMLSpy says you're wrong. The following is well-formed XML:

```
<root>
    <data>'"</data>
</root>
```

---

Aside from "argument by reference to XMLSpy", a better argument is that the XML Serializer has been out in the wild for over seven years. In this time, I guarantee someone has tried to serialize "O'Brien" in a Name property. This bug would have been noticed by now.